# Convert column values into columns and select other column

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite table in this form.

[image]

I want to get this info in this shape to plot it.

[image]

I am using this query but I can't get the values of wordFrequency as you can see.

```
SELECT
Document,
CAST(COALESCE(CASE WHEN Entity="Art" THEN wordFrequency END,0) AS INTEGER) AS Art,
CAST(COALESCE(CASE WHEN Entity="Action" THEN wordFrequency END,0) AS INTEGER) AS Action,
CAST(COALESCE(CASE WHEN Entity="Puzzle" THEN wordFrequency END,0) AS INTEGER) AS Puzzle
FROM __table__
GROUP BY Document;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need aggregate function MAX():

```
SELECT Document,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Entity = 'art' THEN wordFrequency END), 0) AS Art,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Entity = 'action' THEN wordFrequency END), 0) AS Action,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Entity = 'puzzle' THEN wordFrequency END), 0) AS Puzzle
FROM __table__
GROUP BY Document;
```

If the data type of the column `wordFrequency` is `TEXT`, use instead:

```
... THEN wordFrequency + 0 END
```

to convert it implicitly to a number.

Comment: @shahidhamdam did you copy the code as it is? I removed the double quotes from your code.

Comment: Yes I did the same

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5e39565cf91edff0c47893664fc45ce1 there is no syntax error.

Comment: Did you by any chance write backticks instead of single quotes?

Comment: Your query run with double quotes but the values are 0.

Comment: Post sample data here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5e39565cf91edff0c47893664fc45ce1 so I can test it.

Comment: @shahidhamdam check my edited answer. It is 'art' and not 'Art' as you wrote in the query.

Comment: Yeah It worked but with double quotes. With single quotes it was still giving no such column error

Comment: I suspect that you don't use single quotes but backticks. Single quotes is the default for string literals. Double quotes may also be used for column names so avoid them.